# Find each two word string in a list of strings with python re

Tags: python, python-re

I need to extract only two-word strings from a list of strings.

Example list:

```
a = ['word', 'another word', 'yet another word', 'a lot longer word', 'a lot lot longer word', 'and this']
```

So the output should be only this:

```
['another word', 'and this']
```

Comment: `[phrase for phrase in a if phrase.count(' ') == 1]`

Comment: Please define what you mean by "word". Is it any sequence of non-space characters? Is it any sequence of characters in the `\w` set? Are you including only `[A-Za-z]`? There are a variety of assumptions included in the examples which you've provided. Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use re, you can do

```py
two_words = [ x for x in a if len(x.split(' ')) == 2]
```

Using re

```
import re
two_words = [ x for x in a if len(re.findall("(\S+)", x)) == 2]
```